# Can't edit integer of a struct

Tags: c, function, struct

I've got a function that changes the array values of an object, but for some reason I'm unable to change an int value of the same object.
The function is as follows:

```
void storeBook(lib library,book CurrentBook)
{
    library.booklist[library.number_of_books] = CurrentBook;
    library.number_of_books += 1; 
}
```

where the struct is

```
typedef struct library
{
    int number_of_books;
    book *booklist;  
}lib;
```

So I'm able to correctly change the array but the int doesn't change. Since I'm not getting a warning with -w, it makes me think that I'm actually changing the value of a copy of the integer in question. Is this right? How do I rectify it?

Comment: Because a *copy* of the struct is passed to the function, and on return it is forgotten.

Comment: But then how am I able to edit the array for the same struct?

Comment: Please see that answer. You need to pass the function the address of the `struct`.

Comment: @MichaelBohanan When accessing an array, `array[index]` *is* an lvalue reference. It's defined to be equivalent to `*(array+index)`, so you could say it's syntactic sugar for deriving a pointer (by pointer addition) and then dereferencing it. When you pass to a function by value, you only get a copy--there's never any pointers involved, which means the original value cannot be affected. Some other languages (e.g., Java, JavaScript) pass objects by reference (=hidden, auto-dereferenced pointer), but C isn't one one of those languages.

Comment: Yes, that's perfect. Thanks.